# Javascript: check difference in two objects (inner)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm using such code for checking, if two objects are not equal.

(i'm creating patch query string):

```
    var concatUnique = function(a, b) {
      if (b.length === 0) return a;
      return a.indexOf(b[0]) === -1 ? concatUnique(a.concat(b[0]), b.slice(1)) : concatUnique(a, b.slice(1));
    };

    var diffObject = function(a, b) {
      return concatUnique(Object.keys(a), Object.keys(b)).reduce(function(map, k) {
        if (a[k] !== b[k]){
          if (angular.isArray(b[k])){
            if (a[k].toString() !== b[k].toString()){
              map[k] = b[k];
            }
          }
          else{
            map[k] = b[k];
          }
        } 
        return map;
      }, {});
    };

    var compareTwoObjects = function(initialObj, editedObj) {
      var result = diffObject(initialObj, editedObj);
      return JSON.stringify(result);
    };
```

but i have one case:

for example i have such two objects:

```
{a: "1", b: "2", sub: {"1", "2"}}
```

&

```
{a: "1", b: "2", sub: {"1", "3"}}
```

my code will work, but!

if i have such object:

```
{a: "1", b: "2", sub: {c: "1", d: "2"}}
&
{a: "1", b: "2", sub: {c: "1", d: "3"}}
```

it will not work

why it's not using inner object keys?

Comment: You should have a look on https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: @Hitmands i do not need isEqual, because i'm building new object

Comment: For me `compareTwoObjects({a: "1", b: "2", sub: {c: "1", d: "2"}}, {a: "1", b: "2", sub: {c: "1", d: "3"}})` returns  `"{"sub":{"c":"1","d":"3"}}"`. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe you don't want `angular.isArray` there?

Comment: @CarlAmbroselli then i will have another issue